# Screen flickers when playing sound

Tags: x11, audio, intel-graphics

I made the switch from OpenSuse TW to Arch, instead of installing arch from scratch I decided this time to try Arco Linux.

Now, the flickering problem isn't new to me, it happened on Fedora 33 and 34 then on OpenSuse - Leap and Tumbleweed - and now on Arco Linux.

It happens if any sound is played. If a video starts the flickering happens. If I go to spotify web, for example, it will happen, etc.

The flickering takes about 2s. The laptop screen goes first getting completly black and then the second monitor does the same. Then both blink, geting back to normal. I can then pause the music or video and press play again that it won't blink again, only after awhile.

It was hard to find the solution on fedora - gnome - but I then found it, and, it was because of wayland, changing the gdm conf to disable wayland made the trick. On OpenSuse - gnome and i3 - it was the same thing with the same solution - I installed OpenSuse with gnome first, so on i3 the problem was the same.

Now on ArcoLinux I didn't installed it with gnome, I went straight ahead and choose i3. Downloaded my config files, restarted i3 and everything was okay. Opened up brave, went to youtube and played a random video, bam, flickering starts like it always did. I like the other times, went to edit the gdm file, but there wasn't any. I didn't select gdm or any other to be installed. Arco Linux comes with sddm so I tried that but there was nothing there to disable wayland - which yes, it was running. I googled it and it has now been 5 hours since that. I changed kernel from lts to stable, but nothing changed. I then installed gdm, disabled sddm and enabled gdm. Rebooted the system, gnome login screen shows up, I login, everything went fine, just needed to move my edits from .bash_profile to .bashrc. Opened up youtube and it still flickers the screen. I seriously don't know what else to do.

Resume:

- Screen flickers when playing sounds. It as happened 2 times before
  and the same solution dind't work this time.
- Changed kernel from lts to stable (5.13.5-arch1-1). Didn't work.
- Changed from sddm to gdm. This belongs to the - "old" - same
  solution.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

After running the command `dmesg -l err`, I got this output:

```
[    0.181632] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[   17.961054] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: azx_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x20bf8100
[   18.235440] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[   18.871455] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
[   18.871790] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
[   36.231326] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[   37.008073] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
[   37.008419] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
```

Edit 2:

Checked for updates again, there was an update to change " Jack " to " extra/Jack ". It updated alsa and pulseaudio libraries - I think. Rebooted, still the same flickering.

Comment: I have the same. Arch/ Artix Linux, Xorg. Also annoying: This also resets display backlight to some default level. In `dmesg`, I get when it happens only graphics card related stuff (that comes at almost anything related to graphics configuration change): `i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GPIO index 1 request failed (-2)` (8 of them in total, with `index` `1`, `5`, `0`, `0`, `5`, `5`, `5`, `1`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what made it for me.

After running:

```bsh
cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save*
```

and getting `1 Y` as a return value, I tried to change the values with:

```bsh
sudo echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save && sudo  echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
```

This didn't work since I didn't have the permissions. What I had to do was to create `/etc/modprobe.d/audio_disable_powersave.conf` and add `options snd_hda_intel power_save=0` to it.

Rebooted the system and all works well now.

Comment: `sudo echo 1 > filepath` only runs the `echo` as root.  The redirection happens before that, which is why you got permission issues.  Better done with `echo 1 | sudo tee filepath >/dev/null`, or `sudo sh -c 'echo 1 >filepath'`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I didn't know about that, thank you! I was following what a user from reddit told me. He said to do that. Had to find my solution anyways.

Comment: Thanks, that comment pointed me to the solution of the very nasty problem I also had. Audio driver power save ... but why is *audio* power save influencing *video* output? I would like to keep audio power save ...

Comment: @BernardoPiedade: Can you mark the solution that made it work as a solution, please? And: Can you edit your post to fix up the "sudo issue" (you could just post the command to be executed as root, and how to get root is the duty of the user in relation with the system configuration)? Keep the `/etc/modprobe.d/...`-part, because that makes the setting permanent.